# Multiple users can register with same phone in multi factor authentication in auth0

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, auth0, multi-factor-authentication

I am currently working on implementing multi-factor authentication (MFA) using Auth0 for our system.

The problem I am facing is related to the uniqueness of phone numbers during user registration. It seems that multiple users are able to register with the same phone number, which is causing complications in our authentication process.

Ideally, we would like to enforce a rule where each user must have a unique phone number to ensure a seamless and secure multi-factor authentication experience. However, I'm uncertain about the best approach to achieve this within the Auth0 framework.

Could you kindly provide guidance or recommendations on how we can prevent multiple users from registering with the same phone number in the Auth0 system? Any insights, best practices, or configuration adjustments you can share would be greatly appreciated.